# Permissions problems (read only rights) after a mounted nas directory

Tags: raspbian, mount, fstab

I'm trying to mount a folder from a Syno Nas to my Raspberry (OS : Rapsbian). 
The mount is done at every boot.

On my NAS, I added a NFS rule, with read/write rights, with the raspberry's IP address as the host (mapping all the users on the admin account)

I created a directory on the raspberry, /mnt/videoDrive.

I modified the fstab file, adding this :

```
my.syno.nas.ip:/drive /mnt/videoDrive nfs defaults,_netdev,rw 0 0
```

The problem is, the mounted folders are read-only, and I'm unable to create or modify them from the raspberry :

> drwxrwxrwx   2 nobody users  4096 janv. 1 2015  Downloads

I can't figure out where the problem is. Anybody can ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The permissions of a NFS mount is determined by its export on the NFS server. You should check its setting in `/etc/exports` on the NFS server. There are many options to define the permissions; just to point you in the right direction because it is out of scope here on Raspberry Pi.